# S&P 500 Prediction

Tags: stocks, technical-analysis

What technical tools can I use to help predict whether the S&P 500 will rise or fall tomorrow? (Assuming no major events occur)

Comment: Please stop posting joke answers to this question.

Comment: This question is similar to https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/98734/what-is-the-main-factor-for-knowing-a-stock-will-rise-overtime-like-facebook-ap . They differ only in examining an entire index versus a single stock. I tried searching for a more general question that addresses market prediction more broadly but I could not find one.

Answer (score 49):

The S&P 500 goes up most of the time.  So just assume it always goes up.  You will be right most of the time.  This is the basis of most investment advice:  diversify to match the market rather than try to beat the market.

If there were a technical tool that anyone could use that could consistently determine if the S&P were going to go up or down tomorrow, it would stop working almost immediately.  Why?  Because the best way to take advantage of such a tool is to sell it to someone like the Wall Street Journal or Bloomberg.  Then they'd publish it.  Anyone could get the results.  And if you know the S&P is going to go up tomorrow, you can buy today.  What happens when you buy today?  The stocks go up today rather than tomorrow.  But then the tool is wrong about tomorrow.

It is possible through analysis to find gaps in the current stock market consensus.  But this is an ever-moving target.  As soon as the analysis becomes common, it becomes the market consensus, and you have to change to a new analysis.  This makes for a bad answer here, as what we might tell you (if we knew) will be wrong next month even if it is right today.

The best that we could do is point you to Google results, like [5 Tools for Stock Traders](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/investing/5-tools-for-stock-traders/).  That basically says to buy a good charting tool.

The truth is that anyone who has an accurate technical analysis tool is not posting here.  That person is busy trading and making money while dreading the moment when the rest of the market catches up.

Comment: Even during recessions? Also, I know that it is impossible to know how much the market will rise or fall tomorrow but how about what direction it will go?

Comment: Often, the best time to buy is during a recession.  E.g. the best time to buy the S&P 500 in the last twenty years was in the first quarter of 2009.  The recession did not end until June.  Someone who sold on January 2nd, 1998, put the money in the bank, and bought on March 6th, 2009 would have been better off than someone who stayed in the market the whole time.  That's even missing the 1998-2000 period, which produced 50% growth.  And the recession didn't start until 2001, *after* the stock market crash.

Comment: No one can predict day to day movements in the market or even when a crash or recession/bear market will occur.  But it is possible to recognize them when you are in one.  Severe market downturns such as 1987, the 2000 Dotcom Bust, and the 2008 subprime melt down did not happen overnight. Except for the oblivious, along the way one can recognize that market metrics deteriorate - economic indicators turn down, earnings announcement degrade, analyst downgrades and earnings revisions increase, the VIX increases, all beginning long before the crisis becomes acute.

Comment: @chrislam5459 If you know it's impossible to know how much the market will move why on earth could it be possible to know which direction the movement would be?

Comment: I want to say that this is not good advice in the present context and is a very naive approach to prediction that is very likely to lead to medium term losses if it is taken as investment advice. Take a look at the 90 year chart here https://www.macrotrends.net/2324/sp-500-historical-chart-data . This is explained as decreasing trend until post war and bretton woods arrangements . Downward trend after Nixon shock when US defaulted after excessive war spending. Upward trend since 80s when Asian/ oil exporter central bank printing caused present inflation. This period now ending.

Comment: " Because the best way to take advantage of such a tool is to sell it to someone like the Wall Street Journal"

Wait, what, why?

Comment: @NPSF3000 You don't take personal risk if you're wrong (except bad publicity-which still gets your name out there) and if you're right, you get money (presumably more than you could have invested) from those who were successful in using the strategy. And I think selling to a Goldman Sachs or JP Morgan would be much more profitable than selling to "WSJ". In which case, you patent your method and try to get royalties while it still works.

Comment: @NPSF3000 It's similar to all the people who sell "get rich quick in real estate" schemes. They'll claim that they used the scheme to get rich themselves, but this is usually a lie. There's much more money in selling it than using it.

Comment: You're almost at the answer I would say - that any advantage discovered via technical analysis will likely be discovered shortly by other traders since your trades have to be cleared by an exchange and in doing so become semi-public. Upon discovery by other traders, your advantage will be arbitraged away. This is why the adage exists: "There's no such thing as a free lunch"

Comment: "That basically says to buy a good charting tool."  But if it was a good charting tool, then whoever is selling it would be using it to make profitable trades, not trying to sell it.

Comment: The advantage that even the best charting tool gives is not going to be enough to justify making it to an individual.  And the reason that you sell a good tool is that you only have so much money.  Even if your tool doubles your money every year (unlikely), as soon as enough others discover it, it loses its advantage.  If you sell it up front, it loses its advantage immediately but at least you have the money from selling it.  It's like with gold rushes.  Most of the people who got rich weren't the prospectors.  The people who really got rich were the merchants.

Comment: @Brythan A one-size-fits-all "its always better to sell it" is clearly overgeneralised, or RenTech would have presumably sold their technology instead of making ~40-60% a year...

Comment: If you had a tool that made correct predictions most of the time, you could *easily* double your money every few months with leveraged instruments such as futures contracts. Much better than selling it to people and having it lose its advantage, and then those people sue you for losing their money.

Answer (score 15):

My high school economics teacher mentioned that when she worked on Wall Street, she and her coworker would make daily bets on market performance. Her coworker would use a bunch of market data, and she decided to look at the weather (nice day = market up; gloomy day = market down).

She said she won more often, but then again, she's not on Wall Street anymore.

Comment: She's not on Wall Street anymore because the only good stock pickers are monkeys.  "... the company randomly selected 100 portfolios containing 30 stocks from a 1,000 stock universe. They repeated this processes every year, from 1964 to 2010, and tracked the results. The process replicated 100 monkeys throwing darts at the stock pages each year. Amazingly, on average, 98 of the 100 monkey portfolios beat the 1,000 stock capitalization weighted stock universe each year.
https://www.forbes.com/sites/rickferri/2012/12/20/any-monkey-can-beat-the-market/#3a331e77630a

Comment: Well, admittedly, she did leave in late 2001 because her office turned to rubble...

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to accurately predict the movement direction or severety of the stock market or any market index over any time period.

Answer (score 6):

The [Yield curve](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/y/yieldcurve.asp).

If it inverts, the recession is likely (or certain depending on how much you trust the model explaining inverted yield curve vs recession); and thus equity markets will (eventually) fall and the major indices (including S&P) will tend to go down for a while.

Otherwise, on average, the markets are more likely to go up than down, as per Brythan's answer.

Comment: The average time between the yield curve inversion and the recession is 18 months. That's not very useful for predicting the market direction on a specific day.

Comment: If you are certain of it I take it you use your money to short the market as a whole when the yield curve inverts?

Comment: @jbch - as Barmar noted in a comment, the problem is that there is an unknown lag time.